# Datatables associate field value to button while ajax fills table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I'm using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) with AJAX call to put values inside.
I have a delete button that can be remove the user of row from database calling web server. I would like to associate username field to button so I can use this value in my REST call. This is my table:

```
userTable = $('#usersTable').DataTable({
    // disable order and search on column
    columnDefs : [ {
        targets : 1,
        orderable : false,
        searchable : false,
    }, {
        targets : 4,
        orderable : false,
        searchable : false,
    } ],
    // fix problem with responsive table
    "autoWidth" : false,
    "ajax" : "table",
    "columns" : [ {
        "data" : "username"
    }, {
        data : "enabled",
        render : function(data, type, row) {
            if (data) {
                return '<input data="' + row.username + '" type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" checked>';
            } else {
                return '<input data="' + row.username + '" type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox">';
            }
        }
    }, {
        "data" : "role.role"
    }, {
        "data" : "clientVersion.name",
        "defaultContent" : ""// this set empty string if clientVersion.name is null, otherwise datatables shows popup message with error
    }, {
        data : null,
        className : "center",
        defaultContent : '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteUser" data-toggle="modal" data-href=data="' + row.username + '" data-target="#deleteUserModal">Delete</button>'
    } ],
    "fnDrawCallback" : function() {
        // Initialize checkbos for enable/disable user
        $("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch({
            size : "small",
            onColor : "success",
            offColor : "danger"
        });
        // $('#toggleChecked').bootstrapSwitch({size: "small", onColor:"success", offColor:"danger"});
    }
});
```

`row.username` is not available there, does it exist a way to set username value inside button tag?
So then I can use this code to pass the value through modal:

```
//Confirm delete user modal
$('#deleteUserModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
    $('#deleteUserHiddenId').val($(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href'));
});
```

and call:

```
$("#deleteUserModal").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id= $('#deleteUserHiddenId').val();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this

```
$('#usersTable tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
        usernameSelected = (userTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data().username);
    } );
```

where `usernameSelected` is a javascript variable that I use as path variable